# Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function bind_param() on bool in /srv/disk21/3406435/www/l.../login_u.php:21

Tags: php

[image]
Buenas tardes soy nueva en php me gustaria que me ayudaran con el siguiente codigo que me da error en la linea 21, ya busque en otros foros y aun no logro solucionarlo, de antemano gracias! en mi localhost no me da error pero al momento de subirlo a un host es cuando tengo problemas.

Comment: Comprueba si  los dtos estan llegando correctamente a las variables $username y $password, mayormente ese problema se da porque tu consult no esta funcionando bien, verifica si tu consulta esta dando lo esperado, o sea el problema debe estar en la linea 20. por cierto no debería ser : "ss" en vez de "sss"? intenta verificar estos pasos.

Comment: Por favor el código como texto

Comment: Hola, si perdon por el screenshot. Desde mi localhost si  me funcionaba todo bien, el error surgio cuando lo subi a un host.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

tu error se da porque estas pasando 3 `sss` "string" en bind_param
cuando solo tienes `username y password`
debe quedar asi:

```
21 $stmt->bind_param("ss",$username,$password);
22 $stmt->->execute();
23 $result = $stmt->get_result();
while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    $_SESSION['login_user2'] = $row["username"];
}
```

manual:
[bind_param](https://www.php.net/manual/es/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php)

Comment: Hola gracias por responder, ya lo corregi pero aún sigue el mismo error.

Comment: ya hice la correccion intenta ahora

Comment: Gracias pero sigue el mismo problema...

Comment: podrias proveer mas informacion acerca del problema!

Answer (score 0):

Podrías especificar los parametros de la consulta con bindValue, hice un ejemplo:

```
$query = "SELECT username, password
FROM CUSTOMER
WHERE user = :username AND password = :pass 
LIMIT 1";

$stmt = $conn->prepare($query);

$stmt->bindValue(':username', $username, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->bindValue(':pass', $password, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->execute();
```

Con bindValue puedes especificar un parametro de consulta, especificar el dato a introducir en el parametro y de que tipo es el dato introducido, En el que puedes especificar si es de tipo string, int, etc.

Nota: Espero que te sea de utilidad.